# VS 2008 color scheme

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I am looking for the VS 2008 version of 'Oren Ellenbogen's Dark Scheme' color scheme. The scheme available at http://www.lnbogen.com/VisualStudioNet2005Colors.aspx is VS 2005 version. Does anyone have the 2008 version of the same.

The converted verstion at http://tech-nous.blogspot.com/2008/10/visual-studio-2008-colour-schemes.html is not accepted by VS 2008.

Comment: the link is broken, can you provide another link ?

Answer (score 5):

<strike>I think that you'll find that the theme by Rob Conery is very close: http://blog.wekeroad.com/blog/textmate-theme-for-visual-studio-take-2/</strike>

Scott Hanselman has the best collection I've found: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/VisualStudioProgrammerThemesGallery.aspx

Scott also has a link to an XSLT that will help convert 2005 themes to 2008.

edit: Rob Conery link is dead due to blog redesign.

Comment: The first link is broken

Answer (score 2):

It is working for me, on my VS.NET 2008 (hint: I wrote it ;))

Answer (score 0):

You can get some VS2008 Color Schemes from http://winterdom.com/2007/11/vs2008colorschemes

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I am looking for Ellenbogen's Dark Scheme for VS 2008